# Why can't i use webClient with remote server?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, remote-server, downloadstring

this is my code :

```
 public bool login_user(string username, string password)
    {
        // try to login user through php script
        try
        {
            string response = wc.DownloadString(configurationUrl + "login.php?user=" + username + "&password=" + password);
            if (response == "LOGIN_TRUE")
                return true;
        }

        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message);
            UnableToConnect = true;
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

When i navigate to the link that on DownloadString() method directly from browser i see a blank page written on it :

```
LOGIN_TRUE
```

But when i call this function with a correct login and password it returns false.

I see this error only after i transferred my PHP file from local to remote server

What is going wrong here and why this worked on local but not on remote server ?

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Add a watch and see what you are getting for the response variable.could have spaces.

Comment: Also make sure that there is a User / Password setup with rights for that user on the remote server..

Comment: There is no spaces, and also not only this function not work but all similar functions return always false ? the response was "LOGIN_TRUE" without spaces .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Even that i didn't see any white spaces in the string returned when i call the link directly from the browser but it seems that there was some blank spaces and the code above worked by replacing

```
    if (response == "LOGIN_TRUE") return true;
```

by

```
    if (response.Trim() == "LOGIN_TRUE") return true;
```

Thankyou @Codelgnoto